# I am making a timer script in lua but if i stop it the time freezes and jumps forward when i resume it (Minecraft)

Tags: lua

When I stop the timer and start it again, it jumps forward depending on how much time has passed when it was paused.
Link for a video of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xohbzbx4oyVfbRnSMLc_7u1gf7AWMJVy/view?usp=sharing
Code:

```
name = "Stopwatch"
description = "Count time for whatever reason..."

positionX = 0
positionY = 0
sizeX = 24
sizeY = 10
scale = 1

START_STOP_KEY = 0x55 --or 'U'
RESET_KEY = 0x4A --or 'I'
--[[
    Stopwatch Module Script
    

    if you wish to change the key you can take the key code from here
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
]]--

-------------script-code-------------
previoustime = 0
state = 0
startTime = 0
stopTime  = 0

function keyboard(key, isDown)
    if (isDown == true) then
        if (key == RESET_KEY) then
            state = 0
        end
    end
end


function keyboard(key, isDown)
    if (isDown == true) then
        if (key == START_STOP_KEY) then
            if (state == 0) then
                state = 1
                startTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 1) then
                state = 2
                previoustime = os.time()
                stopTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 2) then
                state = 1
                time = previoustime
            end
        end
    end
end

TimerText = "00:00"
TextColor = {r=30,g=255,b=30,a=255}
function doubleDigit(number)
    if (number < 10) then
        return "0" .. math.floor(number)
    else
        return math.floor(number)
    end
end

function timeText(time)
    local result = ""
    local days = 0
    while (time > 86399) do 
        days = days + 1 
        time = time - 86400 
    end

    local hours = 0
    while (time > 3599) do 
        hours = hours + 1 
        time = time - 86400 
    end
    
    local minutes = 0
    while (time > 59) do 
        minutes = minutes + 1 
        time = time - 60 
    end

    if (days == 0) then
        if (hours == 0) then
            return doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        else
            return math.floor(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" ..doubleDigit(time)
        end  
    else
        return math.floor(days) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)  
    end
end

function update()
    if (state == 0) then
        TextColor = {r=30,g=255,b=30,a=255}
        TimerText = "00:00"
    elseif (state == 1) then
        TimerText = timeText(os.time() - startTime)
        TextColor = {r=30,g=255,b=30,a=255}
    elseif (state == 2) then
        TimerText = timeText(stopTime - startTime)
        TextColor = {r=30,g=30,b=255,a=255}
    end
end

function render()
    local font = gui.font()
    local tw = font.width(TimerText)

    gfx.color(0,0,0,120)
    gfx.rect(0, 0, tw + 4, 10)

    gfx.color(TextColor.r, TextColor.g, TextColor.b, TextColor.a)
    gfx.text(2, 1, TimerText)
end
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: and what is your question? how long did you actually think about this problem? I'm asking because it should be pretty obvious, especially to this code's author, why the displayed time jumps if you calculate it from the current time and a constant start time. I mean you pause your timer update, you don't pause the world right?

Comment: Replace `time = previoustime` with `startTime = startTime + os.time() - stopTime`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thx works now!